# gnome keeps restarting on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, matlab, restart, lyx

On Ubuntu 18.04 I am keeping getting intermittent freezes (for like 10 seconds) while using applications like LYX and MATLAB. I went to the sys log and almost everytime that the applications freeze, I see the following logs (see below). It seems that GNOME suddenly decided to restart.

Can anyone give me some clue how to fix this? I am almost getting used to the freezes but they are still annoying.

```
     4:17:21 PM gnome-shell: [27631:27652:0422/161721.104224:ERROR:appcache_update_url_loader_request.cc(139)] Not implemented reached in virtual void content::AppCacheUpdateJob::UpdateURLLoaderRequest::OnTransferSizeUpdated(int32_t)
     4:17:19 PM gnome-keyring-d: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/1, but it's already registered
     4:17:19 PM dbus-daemon: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.bluez.service': Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.
     4:17:02 PM nautilus: g_queue_free: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
     4:17:02 PM systemd: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
     4:17:02 PM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=4782] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
     4:17:01 PM systemd: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
     4:17:01 PM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=4782] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=4921 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
     4:17:01 PM cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
     4:17:01 PM kernel: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
     4:17:01 PM cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
     4:16:57 PM nautilus: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
     4:15:39 PM dbus-daemon: frontends/qt4/Menus.cpp (752): Menu warning: menu entries "Columns/Rows|C" and "Accept Change|c" share the same shortcut.
     4:15:01 PM cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
     4:15:01 PM kernel: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
     4:15:01 PM cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
     4:15:01 PM dbus-daemon: Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 7 language(s) loaded.
     4:06:25 PM gnome-shell: [18202:18223:0422/160625.537633:ERROR:browser_process_sub_thread.cc(209)] Waited 26 ms for network service
     4:05:01 PM cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
     4:04:14 PM kernel: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
     4:04:14 PM kernel: Anacron 2.3 started on 2019-04-22
```

A screenshot is available here:
[System log during freeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XZC2.png)

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this because I've been having the same issue